# d3js add volume bars to line graph

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, linegraph

I built this line graph with d3js: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adwqe2rh/)

Example Data:

```
{
    date: '18-May-18',
    close: 281755783529,
    volume: 11792035643,
    notes: null
}
```

How can I use the "volume" value from data to plot a rectangle bar corresponding to each date? The line graph with volume bars would look something like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because the `volume` uses a different Y-range you need to define a new yScale for that

```
var yVolume = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
yVolume.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.volume; })]);
```

Draw a right axis for this scale

```
var yAxisVol = d3.axisRight(yVolume).ticks(10);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "yaxisVol")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${width},0)`)
  .call(yAxisVol);
```

Then draw the rect on the correct location

```
svg.append("g").attr("class", "barsVol")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "yellow")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(new Date(d.date.getTime()-11*60*60*1000)); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yVolume(d.volume); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yVolume(d.volume); })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
         return x(new Date(d.date.getTime()+11*60*60*1000)) - 
                x(new Date(d.date.getTime()-11*60*60*1000)); });
```

The rectangles have a width of 1 "day" (22 hours).

Add a clip rectangle to the `barsVol` group or extend the x-domain with a day on the left and right.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It does not display properly for me. Do you mind providing an updated fiddle?

Comment: This seems to be creating two different y-axis instead of joining the two

Comment: Not likely that the max of `close` and max of `volume` have similar value because they describe something different. So to take full use of the height for the bars you need a new yScale because the domain differs. In your example the values differ a factor of 10.